# VS2010 debug output not showing up in DbgView

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug an application in VS2010. The code for this application has a lot of debug statements to help identify any error conditions. I do see these statements in the VS2010, but those are not being shown in the DbgView. Normally, I have a number of filters setup in DbgView which helps to easily identify & classify all the debug information that is being written by the debug statements. Since the VS2010 debug window does not have this filter functionality, its very difficult to find things in the debug output. Previously I was using VS2005 and the Debug.Write() calls showed up in both the VS2010 debug window as well as the DbgView window.

Is there a way to redirect/duplicate VS2010  Debug window output to DbgView?

Comment: Works fine on my machine™.  Make sure you're not running in 64-bit mode, maybe.

Comment: Hi Hans, how can I check that? I assumed that it is running in 32bit mode since my machine is a winXP 32 bit machine.

Comment: Stupid question, but are you running it in debug mode under VS2010? If you are actually running it debugged then no debug output should ever get to dbgview, the code which implements OutputDebugString first checks if a debugger is attached (and sends a debug event if it is), otherwise it tries to find some special events and named sections and uses that to write the debug output (which is what dbgview implements).